# Regex - retrieve some words between two strings

Tags: regex

I'm new to regex and I need to retrieve some string from a this text:

```
    Begin
    .....
    .....
    To: alias nameX <aaa@tt.com>; alias nameY <yyy@tt.com>
    From: alias name <bbb@tt.com> 
    CC: alias name1 <ccc1@tt.com>; alias name2 <ccc2@tt.com>; alias name3; 
alias name4 <ccc4@tt.com>; alias name5 <ccc5@tt.com>
    Subject: This is a regular expression text
    .....
    .....
    End
```

With `<(.*?)>`I can select everything between '<' and '>'.

I want t get everything between '<' and '>' starting on "CC:" and ending in "Subject:" without the '<' and '>' signs.

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: Something like [`(?m)(?:^CC:|\G(?!\A)(?=.*\RSubject:))[^<]*<\K[^<>]+`](https://regex101.com/r/dxNF8Y/1)?

Comment: Try Regex regex = new Regex("Cc(.*)Subject");

Comment: .NET: [`(?m)(?<=^CC.*?<)[^<>]+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%28%3f%3c%3d%5eCC.*%3f%3c%29%5b%5e%3c%3e%5d%2b&i=Begin%0d%0a.....%0d%0a.....%0d%0aTo%3a+alias+nameX+%3caaa%40tt.com%3e%3b+alias+nameY+%3cyyy%40tt.com%3e%0d%0aFrom%3a+alias+name+%3cbbb%40tt.com%3e+%0d%0aCC%3a+alias+name1+%3cccc1%40tt.com%3e%3b+alias+name2+%3cccc2%40tt.com%3e%3b+alias+name3%3b+alias+name3+%3cccc4%40tt.com%3e%3b+alias+name5+%3cccc5%40tt.com%3e%0d%0aSubject%3a+This+is+a+regular+expression+text%0d%0a.....%0d%0a.....%0d%0aEnd)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions for this task. Use a proper library for parsing mail headers.